# Unable to click button programatically in UIWebView (Webpage)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c

I am trying to programatically click on a single button on a webpage in UIWebView using

```
NSString *jsStat = @"document.getElementsByName('btn btn-info')   [0].click()";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsStat];
```

but the button has not been clicked programatically.
My button Class name is "btn btn-info" and button's properties are

```
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" class="btn btn-info">
```

and complete page is

```
<form action="https:www.googleabc.com"post">
<input type=hidden name=ID value="myvalue" /><input type=Hidden name=Style value=STL:18/>
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" class="btn btn-info">
```

Am i missing something here? or there is any better solution than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementsByName`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-info')[0].click()
```

---

Working example:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-info')[0].click()
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" class="btn btn-info" onClick="console.log('Clicked!')">
```